# Flow and module keyword stripping

Tags: module, babeljs, flowtype

To get the Flow type-checker to work with multiple files you need to import and export modules, but the basic setup with Babel does not erase the module keywords, leading to browser problems like

> SyntaxError: export declarations may only appear at top level of a module

and

> SyntaxError: import declarations may only appear at top level of a module

What's the proposed solution to this?

My babelrc:

```
{
  "plugins": [
    "transform-flow-strip-types"
  ]
}
```

The Javascript source

```
export class MyClass {}
```

gets transformed to the exact same.

Wanted output is

```
class MyClass {}
```

Comment: `export class MyClass {}` is ES6, not Flow, Flow just know how to process ES6.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `transform-flow-strip-types` plugin only removes Flow syntax extensions, but import/export is part of the ES2015 spec. To compile those as well, you need to add some more plugins. `preset-es2015` will include these by default or you can use one of the `babel-plugin-transform-es2015-modules-*` plugins. Hope this helps!